# Parsing in JS gets me a SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

An error pop out when I try to parse a JSON object (or at least I guess it should be an object since there's `"content-type": "application/json` in the response's header). Here is the full error stack I get :

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
    handleUpdate index.jsx:55
    UserUpdateForm index.jsx:77
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 3
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:644
    __require chunk-HV27UI33.js:9
    js index.js:6
    __require chunk-HV27UI33.js:9
    React 2
    __require chunk-HV27UI33.js:9
    js React
    __require chunk-HV27UI33.js:9
    <anonymous> react-dom:1
index.jsx:55:24
```

from this code :

```
    const handleUpdate = async ({ username, email }) => {
        const token = Cookies.get("token");
        const body = { user: { username: username, email: email } };
        const res = await update(`/users/${currentUser.id}`, body, token);
        const response = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
            handleChange(response);
        }
    };
```

where `update()` is :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from "./config.js";

const update = async (
  endpoint,
  body = null,
  jwt_token = null,
  header = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }) => {

  let opt = header;
  if (jwt_token){
      opt["Authorization"] = jwt_token
  }

  try {
    return await axios.patch(BASE_URL + endpoint, body, { headers: opt })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`An error occurred while trying to fetch ${endpoint}. ${err}`);
  }
}

export default update;
```

I already found answers to similar issues, talking about a problem of data not encoded in UTF-8, but I don't think it is my case. The really weird thing is that I don't have such issues with other components using similar request (I built `post` requests that are really similar and do not produce any issue in the components they are used in). **And if I don't parse the response I get from the server, `response.data.attributes` would be `undefined`, even though there are keys `data` and `attributes`.**

**Edit :** here is the header of the response. As we can see, there is a parameter `content-type: application/json` :

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
server: nginx
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 09:02:11 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-sso-wat: You've just been SSOed
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
access-control-expose-headers: 
access-control-max-age: 7200
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-download-options: noopen
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
etag: W/"***
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: ***
x-runtime: 0.053418
vary: Origin
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
content-security-policy-report-only: default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

**Edit 2:** as suggested in another Stackoverflow thread, I tried to parse a stringified response. It felt like pranking JS, but ok, it avoided the "JSON.parse: unexpected character" issue. Meaning : the initial response is a JSON object, BUT **I still cannot access `response.data.attributes`** ... This is wizardry.

Comment: you need to log `res` before its parsed - maybe the Axios API already converted it into a native object?

Comment: Check the request in the browser console Network tab.  See what the response is.  It won't be JSON.

Comment: It does not change anything if I console.log `res` before it is parsed. And in the "Network" tab it is well specified that the response is in JSON format.

Comment: It's not that logging `res` before it is parsed will *change* anything, it's that looking at the log will help you figure out if you are in fact dealing with a JSON object.

Comment: I edited the post with a complete response header. It shows `content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. So my guess is I do not need to parse the response, but then I don't how to access `response.data.attributes`, since a log of this returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

axios parses the response automatically, so it is already an object.  The error is coming from trying to parse something that is not a string, but an object.